# Get the correct index of dictionary

Tags: objective-c, indexing, nsmutablearray

```
    NSMutableArray *tmpMutArr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:allObjectsArray];
    NSLog(@"The content of array is%@",tmpMutArr);

    int index;

     for (int i=0;i<[tmpMutArr count];i++) 
     {
     if([[tmpMutArr  objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
     {
     NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [tmpMutArr  objectAtIndex:i];
         if([[tempDict valueForKey:@"Name"] isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", nameString]])
     {
     index = i;

     }
     }
     }

     [tmpMutArr replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:mutDict]];
```

This code is not replacing the **matching object in tmpMutArr** as I want it to, but replaces **all objects in tmpMutArr** instead. How to replace only the index I want?

I know that tmpMutArr containing all objects before the replacement, so I just need to specify the index correctly I think. How to do so?

Comment: you intentions are really unkown. Kindly be more comprehensive in your asking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *tmpMutArr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:allObjectsArray];
NSLog(@"The content of array is%@",tmpMutArr);

int index;

for (int i=0;i<[tmpMutArr count];i++) 
{
    if([[tmpMutArr  objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [tmpMutArr  objectAtIndex:i];
        if([[tempDict valueForKey:@"Name"] isEqualToString:nameString])
        {
            index = i;
            break; // << added break
        }
    }
}

[tmpMutArr replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:mutDict]];
```

Comment: Yep, I just copy-paste-formatted OP's sourcecode. Thanks for noticing, @H2CO3.

Comment: you're welcome (that happened to me as well, I'm just overly sensitive to redundance in code since it wastes processor time ;)

Answer (score 0):

maybe, you should try to this version... you have not specified which index is needed, I suppose the first one.

```
for (int i=0;i<[tmpMutArr count];i++) {
     if([[tmpMutArr  objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
         NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [tmpMutArr  objectAtIndex:i];
         if([[tempDict valueForKey:@"Name"] isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", nameString]]) {
             index = i;
             break; // when you find the first one, you should go out from the iteration
         }
     }
 }
```