# Remove NSDictionary from NSUserdefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I would like to remove an NSDictionary that is stored in NSUserdefaults.
I tried with this :

```
[NSUserDefaults removeObjectForKey:@"bookmarks"];
```

But, all my favorites are removed

How can I delete one single favorite?

I found the same question here 
- [Remove object of NSUserDefault by tableview cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646403/remove-object-of-nsuserdefault-by-tableview-cell)

thanks all

Comment: what is your favourite ? is it a key in the dictionary you removed ? or is it another dictionary ?

Comment: its another dictionary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the dictionary of bookmarks, creating a *mutable copy*, so you can modify it:

```
NSMutableDictionary *bookmarks = [[userDefaults objectForKey:@"bookmarks"] mutableCopy];
```

Remove the one you want:

```
[bookmarks removeObjectForKey:@"Bookmark be gone"];
```

Put the bookmarks back:

```
[userDefaults setObject:bookmarks forKey:@"bookmarks"];
```

and sync:

```
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

**EDIT** Following a comment from the OP, it sounds like it might be in an array, rather than a dictionary.  The principle is the same:

Get the array of bookmarks, creating a *mutable copy*, so you can modify it:

```
NSMutableArray *bookmarks = [[userDefaults objectForKey:@"bookmarks"] mutableCopy];
```

Remove the one you want (to find the index of the object you probably need to iterate the array.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958338/get-the-correct-index-of-dictionary)):

```
[bookmarks removeObjectAtIndex:5];
```

Put the bookmarks back:

```
[userDefaults setObject:bookmarks forKey:@"bookmarks"];
```

and sync:

```
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

Comment: thanks for you reply. But i dont have key in my dictionary and it doesnt work. How can i delete by indexpath?

Comment: @Seb78 Sounds like it's in an array, not a dictionary?